# Cron email not taking store smtp in multi site environment

Tags: magento2, cron, smtp

We have a multi site magento installation. For each website, we have configured different smtp settings.

But, when we run cron to send abandoned cart email, it is always selecting the default smtp settings and not the store smtp settings for each website.

How to implement the store smtp setting while running cron.

Comment: Please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261694/39238.