# How to emulator Store View by Store ID Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2

M2.3.5_p2
I was using class method

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\AttributeMetadataCache->load($entityType, $suffix = '');


public function load($entityType, $suffix = '')
{
    $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    if (isset($this->attributes[$entityType . $suffix . $storeId])) {
        return $this->attributes[$entityType . $suffix . $storeId];
    }
    if ($this->isEnabled()) {
        $cacheKey = self::ATTRIBUTE_METADATA_CACHE_PREFIX . $entityType . $suffix . $storeId;
        $serializedData = $this->cache->load($cacheKey);
        if ($serializedData) {
            $attributesData = $this->serializer->unserialize($serializedData);
            $attributes = [];
            foreach ($attributesData as $key => $attributeData) {
                $attributes[$key] = $this->attributeMetadataHydrator->hydrate($attributeData);
            }
            $this->attributes[$entityType . $suffix . $storeId] = $attributes;
            return $attributes;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to load all attributes metadata. It worked perfectly until I used it to get data by scope storeview in adminhtml. In detail, whenever order load, i would try to load all attributes metadata by order store view id and I expected receive all attributes metadata flow the order store view. But it always return all attributes metadata on default store view. Can I handle this issue?

I try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261694/68534) but does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use emulation as per **store view** **using store id** as below

```
 /**
  * \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
  */
 protected $emulation;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation) {
   $this->emulation = $emulation;
}

public function example($storeId) {
  
   //define area according to your requirement like frontend or adminhtml
   $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
   
   //do your code here
   
   // stop the emulated environment after your code
   $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
   
}
```